# How to fix the isue "same ID "923" already exists." when update version 2.1.7 to 2.2.2?

Tags: magento2

Today I updated magento 2 from 2.1.7 to 2.2.2. when done I tried edit product but get issue.

> Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor) with the same ID
>   "923" already exists.

I looking in database but not result see is the item duplicated.
this is code be use:

```
SELECT * FROM cataloginventory_stock_item where product_id in (SELECT product_id FROM cataloginventory_stock_item GROUP BY product_id HAVING ( COUNT(product_id) > 1 ))
```

Comment: Please check the increment id should be primary and set to auto increment in mysql

Comment: thanks u @PurushotamSharma. I checked in this table has set auto increment.